# Django cannot run server

Tags: python, django

[image]

I just started learning Django 
and it's stopping me from the beginning.
as you can see from the image, whenever I try to runserver Errno 11001 comes in.
So I googled it and seemed like proxy problem
so I tried everything I could find but nothing fixed it.
(environmental variables, trying different proxys, etc..)

Can anybody helpme plzzzz

Answer (score 5):

Even though Django's [official starter tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/) suggests that we can use '0' as a shortcut for IP '0.0.0.0' the command `runserver` throws an error `Error: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed` when the shortcut is used with it.

Use

`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

to listen on all available public IPs on port 8000 instead of

`python manage.py runserver 0:8000`

Answer (score 1):

No, that's now how you should run the server you have to pass ip address and port number like this

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:800
```

hope this helps!

Comment: OK it was because hostname of my computer was in Korean. So I got that UnicodeError. Thx guys for trying to help me

Comment: @dntkald Please mark answers as correct to close this.

Answer (score 0):

Run Django server with this command

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Or

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Here, `8000` is port, you can use other port as well.

Comment: I get ''UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 0: invalid continuation byte'' when I try that.

Comment: @dntkald That's actually a different problem. Try searching for that, you will find questions regarding that.

Comment: OK it was because hostname of my computer was in Korean. So I got that UnicodeError. Thx guys for trying to help me.

Comment: @dntkald Welcome. Have a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).